# Javafx: tooltip for combobox items in treetablecell

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tooltip, javafx-8

Is there a simple way to add a `Tooltip` to the `ComboBox` items in the `ComboBoxTreeTableCell` ?

Comment: hmm ...what do you mean exactly? the items in the dropdown? that would be the same as a standalone combo (use a custom cell factory)

Comment: Exactly, I thought to use a custom cell factory, but then I have to modify a lot in my class which is already a custom ComBoxTreeTableCell, but there is no reference for the comboBox so I could not set a custom factory. At the moment I solved by getting a reference via `lookup` then setting a custom cell factory, but I think it is not the most elegant solution.  As I know there is no other way to customize the item node in the comboBox or?

Comment: ahh I see ... no there's no way to grab the combo in a custom subclass of ComboBoxXXCell - lookup, listen to changes in children or reflectively accessing the private field is a matter of taste and freedom of evilness :)

Comment: It might be easier to write your own implementation of `TreeTableCell`. It would be nice if the provided cell implementations exposed protected methods that created the editing controls (e.g. `protected ComboBox<T> createComboBox(StringConverter<T> converter)`, or something similar). Maybe worth a feature request...

Comment: @James_D ackn - most will have their own implementations anyway due to editing being completely broken in core cells ..

Comment: So, I suppose the answer to the question "Is there a *simple* way to ...." is a pretty resounding "no". The answer to "Is there a way to ..." is "It's complicated".

Comment: @James_D Yeah I was looking for something similar but I didn't get anything. As I mentioned earlier at the moment I am using the `lookup` way to solve the problem, but I didn't really know how bad is to use. To rewrite a new `ComboBoxTreeTableCell` it is much more complicated than to use lookup, so now I am using the simplest but ugly way. Myabe I was not enough precise at questioning.